# Custom commit messages for every different file PhpStorm + GitHub

Tags: git, github, phpstorm, commit-message

That's my first question on StackOverflow, so every advice will be very appreciated.

I'm working with PhpStorm as IDE, and my partners and I are we using GitHub as a Version Control System.

Every time you make a commit change (like a *push*) Git allows you to add a comment on the files that you change.

***And we arrive to the problem***

As you can see on this image I have changed 3 files (1 php class file, and 2 twig templates):

[image: img]

The problem is that **I want to add a commit message for every different file**, but the commit message box only allows you to comment every file with the same comment.

The only way to do that is committing **every file separately**, but I want a faster way.

Comment: Can't you just remove the ticks from checkboxes ? (not a phpstorm user, just guessing .. which is why this not an "answer")

Comment: you are committing a change, if the change affect multiple files then you should reflect that in your comment.

Comment: @meda that would be very limiting view on version control. Besides, he does not want to commit all the three changes, because each of those files was probably changed because of a different reason.

Comment: You're not committing files, you're committing snapshots of your entire worktree, so when git forces you to write 1 commit message for all the files you're committing this is not just to be obtuse, but 1 commit equals 1 commit message. If that commit contains 1000 files, that commit will still have 1 commit message. If you want to have 1 commit message per file you will have to make 1 commit per file as well. You want a faster way, but really... **why**? Why do you want to commit each file separately?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I express myself wrong, or you don't understand me. I don't want to commit each file separately , i wan't to add a different commit-message to each file. Cause the changes on every file could be different.

Comment: Then you simply write: `file1: Change A, file2: Change B: file3: Change C`, and so on. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want, but that's all you can do.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that's exactly what I'm doing, but seems dirty for me

Comment: Yes, you're right, it **does** seem dirty, but that is because you're lumping together unrelated changes. **That** is the dirty part. If you fixed bug X, that's what your commit message should say, the number of files attached to the commit is a detail about your fix. If, on the other hand, your one commit contains 1 unrelated change per file, then you're basically not using source control right. Fix one thing at a time, commit, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not allow creating different commit messages for each file in a commit. See e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073808/git-commit-comment-per-file) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171022/git-commit-multiple-files-but-add-messages)

So you need to commit each file separately if you wat a different message.

Comment: I see: "The Git philosophy is to track 'content', not 'files". thanks for the links Dmitriy

Answer (score 1):

There is no faster way in PhpStorm. The commit message is about the change you're committing, which is not file-specific. If you want to have a different commit message per file, you need to split them over multiple commits. The only potential way to do it faster, is to not use PhpStorm but to do it from the command line (assuming you have `git` installed).

First run `git status` to make sure nothing is staged for commit yet. If there is, run `git reset HEAD path\to\file` to unstage the files.

Then, per file, you can add them (one file at a time, one folder at a time, or whatever's left) and commit with a message. Note: I use a Linux machine for development and have never tried running git from the Windows command prompt, but I assume the commands are the same on Windows:

```
git add src\Controller\UserController.php
git commit -m "Commit message for UserController.php"

git add src\View\templates
git commit -m "Commit message for home.twig and publicProfile.twig"

git add .
git commit -m "Commit message for remaining files, like in web\assets\js"

git push
```

`git push` should push those 3 commits to Github for you.

Comment: As you said, this is a way, but far to be a fastest way :(